# Python Pandas: update dataframe values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:  (**update:** I've added one column `stuff`to `df1` to specify that the two dataframes have not the same schemas)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3'], 
                    'val': [0, 0, 0], 
                    'stuff': ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['2','3'], 'val': [10, 20]})

print(df1)
  id  val stuff
0  1    0   foo
1  2    0   bar
2  3    0  spam

print(df2)
  id  val
0  2   10
1  3   20
```

I want to update the values in `df1` `val` column with the values from `df2` `val` column based on the `id` column. Desired result after transformation on `df1`:

```
print(df1)
  id  val stuff
0  1    0   foo
1  2   10   bar
2  3   20  spam
```

I could use a join (`merge`) but then I would need several more steps to end up with the expected result (casting the column from float to int, dropping column, etc.). (BTW, if you have a simple and elegant way to it with a join, I am also interested).
I am trying to use slicing methods but could not figure out how. Example:

```
>>> df1.loc[df1['id'].isin(df2['id']), 'val'] = df2['val']
```

gives:

```
print(df1)
  id   val stuff
0  1   0.0   foo
1  2  20.0   bar
2  3   NaN  spam
```

<strike>**Update:** One more constraint: do not modify the original `df1` index.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

You could also do `map`

```
In [88]: df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['val']).fillna(df1['val'])
Out[88]:
0     0.0
1    10.0
2    20.0
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

---

```
In [89]: df1['val'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['val']).fillna(df1['val'])

In [90]: df1
Out[90]:
  id   val
0  1   0.0
1  2  10.0
2  3  20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using a `merge`:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='id')
df1['val'] = np.where(df1['val_y'].isnull(), df1['val_x'], df1['val_y'])
# recast to int
df1['val'] = df1['val'].astype(int)
# remove extra columns
df1.drop(['val_x', 'val_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df1)
  id stuff  val
0  1   foo    0
1  2   bar   10
2  3  spam   20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `drop duplicates`

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).set_index('id').drop_duplicates().reset_index()

    id  val
0   1   0
1   2   10
2   3   20
```

If you don't want to modify original index then something like this will work.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3'], 'val': [0, 0, 0] ,
                       'stuff': ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['2','3'], 'val': [10, 20] })

df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
# df1.val = df1.val.astype(int) # convert to int

print(df1)
   id   val    stuff
0   1   0       foo
1   2   10      bar
2   3   20      spam
```

Comment: This works if df1 and df2´have the same schema. What if df1 have more columns? And I would prefer not to touch the original `df1`index. 
I've edited the question to take this into account.